# GraphicImage alt not visible while using rendered condition

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a graphicimage in my xhtml whick I am loading on some condition:

Here is the component:

```
<h:graphicImage id="imgHlpProfileClass" 
                        styleClass="helpIcon" 
                        url="/images/icons/dashboard_help_16.png" 
                        alt="Help Text"/>
```

In this case the text in alt is displayed.

But when I apply rendered condition in component the alt attribute is not displayed.

Example:

```
<h:graphicImage id="imgHlpProfileClass" 
                        styleClass="helpIcon" 
                        url="/images/icons/dashboard_help_16.png" 
                        alt="Help Text"
                        rendered="#{not empty targetSource.object.type}"/>
```

**EDIT:**

I have made the changes like this. The rendered attribute is correctly working for both the output text as well as GraphicalImage. But in case of Graphical Image the alt is not working. What is wrong here?

```
<h:panelGroup id = "overrideProvisioningActionTextPanel">
          <h:outputText value="Override Default Provisioning" 
                        rendered="#{not empty targetSource.object.type}"/>
          <h:graphicImage id="imgHlpAppCase" 
                        styleClass="helpIcon" 
                        url="/images/icons/dashboard_help_16.png" 
                        alt="Help Text"
                        rendered="#{not empty targetSource.object.type}"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: the expression in the "rendered" attribute will be evaluated to true or false no matter it's valid or not. You must check if your expression is correct or makes sense (try adding another component to the same page that prints its value for example)

Comment: Yes the same expression is applied to the other component also and it works well.

Comment: is the problem happenning when you're trying to update this component? If it was not rendered when the page was loaded, then the component is not there and the "update" clause will be ignored and you'll have to wrap your image inside another "re-renderable" component

Comment: When did `alt` not display? When `rendered` is `false`, did you mean?

Comment: i have made changes to question. If i remove rendered condition, alt text shows up. Why so?

Comment: @BalusC No it is never displayed.

Comment: You mean, also when `rendered` is `true`?

Comment: Yeah so the Graphical image is not displayed when the render attribute is false. But when it is true the image comes but not the alt text.

Comment: Okay. Tell the JSF impl/version (you should do that in **every** question, you know).

Comment: By the way, just to avoid some confusion, are you well aware of the difference between `alt` and `title` attributes? Some starters namely incorrectly think that the `alt` attribute would show up as tooltip when you hover the image. In case you're unsure, view page source or inspect element and check if `alt` attribute is really in the generated HTML output.

Comment: @BalusC i want the same functionlaity when i hover on the image it should show as tooltip. I looked into the firebug and the alt text is present in the <img> tag but it is not shown on UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing `alt` with `title`.

The `alt` is only shown as replacement text when the image is broken, or when the enduser is using a client which doesn't load images like screenreaders. Moreover, searchbots also use `alt` as keyword to match images. The `alt` is **not** intented as tooltip. Therefor the `title` attribute should be used (like as on every other component/element). The appearance of `alt` and `title` is also different. The `alt` displays as inline text while the `title` displays only on hover.

So, this is what you ultimately need:

```
<h:graphicImage ... title="Help Text" />
```

This all has nothing to do with presence of `rendered` attribute. You'd have exactly the same problem when removing it (while having a working image!).

#### See also:

- [Basic HTML tutorial - the `<img>` element](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/img/)

Comment: +1... I have used title and it is perfectly working now. But I am curious why it is not working using alt with the same condition. Ideally it should work in both the cases. Is there any reason behind it?

Comment: The `rendered` condition has no influence. It's more likely that you wasn't running the code you thought was running, or that there was a misobservation because the image was actually broken. In the future, better create a MCVE to exclude own misobservations.

Comment: If I remove the rendered condition it works fine. I think there is something that I am missing. I have to check and I will get back to you.